# Where are RDP permission settings stores in Windows Server 2008?

Tags: rdp

For example, the settings to allow userA, but disallow userB on RDP?

Comment: For what? The server's RDP settings or the MSTSC's settings for the client?

Comment: I store myself in c:\config.sys - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CONFIG.DOS

Comment: the server's RDP settings, see updated question.

Comment: @AndrewSmith Not sure if troll.

Answer (score 7):

The ability to login to a Windows Computer via is a bit spread out.

- The settings for the RDP listener process can be found in this MMC.

  - `Administrative Tools\Terminal Services\Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration`
- Open the `RDP-Tcp` connection, and click the `Security` tab.

By default there will be settings to permit anyone in the `local\Administrators`, and `local\Remote Desktop Users` groups.  The standard practice is to simply add the users, or groups you want to have access to one of these groups.  Though if you have some unusual requirements you can go into the security properties for the RDP listener, and setup permissions there.

Another method you can use to modify the membership of the `Remote Desktop Users` group by right clicking on My computer, going into the properties, and clicking the `Remote Settings` tab.  The `Select Users` dialog is just controlling the membership of the `Remote Desktop Users` group.

Comment: Are those settings stored in a specific file? (for example a XML file)

Comment: Like frederik said it is in the registry.

Answer (score 1):

They are most likely stored in the registry database, along with almost all the other windows settings.

Comment: After your edit, i know those settings are set in the GUI of for example server manager, and I am pretty sure those values are stored in the registry too.

Comment: After some search, I havent been able to find the place.
However, you can run this command to enable a rdp user:
`NET LOCALGROUP "Remote Desktop Users" <DOMAIN>\<User> /ADD`